# Bias of estimator for difference of expectations of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Apologize if this is a simple question, I have not been able to find a satisfactory response anywhere.

Suppose we have two random variables $X$, $Y$, and $n$ samples from each: $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$. We are interested in estimating their absolute difference of expectations, $|\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]|$. Online, I found that an estimator for this quantity is:
$$\left|\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_i-y_j)\right|.$$
I am curious about the bias for this estimator, in particular as a function of $n$.

When $n=1$ the estimate is clearly biased, as it produces $|x_1-y_1|$, which has expected value $\mathbb{E}\left[|X-Y|\right]$.

For $n>1$ I am having a more difficult time analyzing. It is unbiased in this case? Is it biased with a bias decreasing as $n$ increases?

Comment: The expression can also be written as $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n y_j\right| = \left|\bar x -\bar y\right|$. It is biased unless $\mathbb P(X>Y=0)$ or $\mathbb P(X<Y=0)$, since otherwise you could have the sign of $\bar x -\bar y$ being opposite to $|\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]|$.  But I would expect the probability of that to decrease as $n$ increases and so to see the bias decrease.

Comment: We have $E|X-Y| \geq | E (X-Y) |$. This inequality is strict outside of special circumstances, so if you use this inequality on your estimator, you will see that it isbiased in general. One special circumstance where we have equality is that $X-Y$ is constant. The bias decreases as $n\to \infty$. To see this intuitively, as $n\to \infty$, your estimator will become close to the constant $|E(X-Y)|$ by a law of large numbers. In the limit, this means the bias becomes $E|E(X-Y)| - | E (X-Y) |=0$.

Comment: Writing $Z = X - Y$ and $z_i=x_i-y_i$, your estimator is simply $|\overline{Z}|$, the absolute value of the sample mean of $z_i$'s. So, (1) LLN tells that $|\overline{Z}|$ converges to $|\mathbf{E}[Z]|$ as $n\to\infty$, and (2) the inequality $$\mathbf{E}\bigl[\bigl(|\overline{Z}|-|\mathbf{E}[Z]|\bigr)^2\bigr]\leq\mathbf{Var}(\overline{Z})=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Var}(Z)$$ can be used to quantify the concentration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This estimator is always biased. Using Jensen's inequality:

\begin{align}
E\left| \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i - y_j) \right| &\geq \left| E\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i - y_j)\right) \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left(E(X)-E(Y) \right)\right| \\
&= \left|E(X)-E(Y) \right|
\end{align}

Furthermore, for Jensen, we have equality if and only if the function is affine (it is not in this case) or if $x_i - y_j$ is constant for all $i$ and $j$. As long as this is not the case, the inequality is strict.

Thus, we have that

$$
E\left| \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i - y_j) \right| - \left|E(X)-E(Y) \right| > 0
$$

In other words, the estimator is biased, and furthermore, the bias is always positive.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something just like this. I think you meant to say or if $x_i-y_j$ is constant for all $i$ and $j$ however (rather than $=0$)

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I'll correct that now.